# Regular expression to replace string in actionscript 3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

My Regular expression is :

> /(url="\S+")/

And my string is

```
<code url="http://ns.adobe.com/textLayout/2008"><p>"test"</p></code>
```

I want replace this url value with an empty string.

```
str=str.replace(/(url="\S+")/, "");
```

but the output is coming like

```
<code </p></code>
```

I want the output like:
`<code ><p>"test"</p></code>`

Can anyone tell me what's my mistake???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `str=str.replace(/(url="[^"]+")/, "");`, it is safer.

See [example](https://regex101.com/r/oW4lI2/1).

The problem is with `\S+` that means **match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ] as many times as possible (greedy)** including `<` and `>`.